# Compiling goog.net.XhrIo in Advanced Compilation Mode (Google Closure API)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, google-closure-library

My program produced an error at run time when the following code is compiled with ADVANCED_COMPILATION flag and executed:

```
    goog.net.XhrIo.send(htmlURL, function(e) { // Theatre.js 122
    var xhr = e.target;
    var htmlText = xhr.getResponseText();
    htmlExtractor.extract(htmlText, 'body');
});
```

Through the source maps, Chrome's console give this trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined eventtarget.js:222
s.Db                eventtarget.js:222
We                  xhrio.js:308
of                  Theatre.js:122
```

xhrio.js:308

```
 x.listen(goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, opt_callback);
```

eventtarget.js:222

```
  return this.eventTargetListeners_.add(
  String(type), listener, false /* callOnce */, opt_useCapture,
  opt_listenerScope);
```

The code didn't have this problem when compiled in simple mode. I can't think of something on my end that could cause the eventTargetListeners_ to be undefined. Would anyone knows what could have cause this problem? Or any suggestions for how to approach this problem?

Thanks

(P.S From http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-790, I think some folks from the ClojureScript development might have solved this issue, but I don't know ClojureScript enough to know how.)

Comment: Are both the library and compiler up to date?

Comment: Yes, I cloned the master branch on Git a week ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the namespace gotchas for clojurescript when coming from clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723111/what-are-the-namespace-gotchas-for-clojurescript-when-coming-from-clojure)